# Covert Access Cross tab to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I need this converted to a SQL view. This is the code from MS Access:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Products.Id) AS AntalOfId
SELECT Products.[id]
FROM Sold INNER JOIN (Products INNER JOIN Cat ON Products.BelsCategoryId = Cat.[Id]) ON Sold.BelsProductId = Products.[id]
GROUP BY Products.[id]
PIVOT Sold.Year;
```

Any ideas how to re write this into SQL ?

In products I have id, BelsCategoryID.
In Categories, I have ID.
In Sold, I have BelsProductID and year. - This table shows weather a product is sold in a given year.

I want the result with year as a header and then 0 or 1, if the product has been sold in a given year

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using Access 2019 and SQL server manager v. 18.3.1

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, specify the database you are targetting.

Comment: In products I have id, BelsCategoryID.
In Categories, I have ID
In Sold, I have BelsProductID and year. - This table shows weather a product is sold in a given year.

I want the result as follow

ProductID     2017    2018    2019    2020
1                   1          0          0          1
2                   0          1          1          1
3                   1          0          1          0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRANSFORM` doesn't have an exact match in other databases, because it can produce a variable number of columns.  For a given set of years, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Sold.Year = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as year_2020,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Sold.Year = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as year_2019,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Sold.Year = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as year_2018       
FROM Products INNER JOIN
     Cat 
     ON Products.BelsCategoryId = Cat.[Id] INNER JOIN
     Sold 
     ON Sold.BelsProductId = Products.[id]
GROUP BY Products.[id]
```

If you want a flexible number of years, you need to use dynamic SQL.